# How to avoid unreasonable long response time by using .net webclient with proxy?

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, webclient

I am trying to just request the webpage by using webclient DownloadString method with proxy.

The following is my code:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        wc.Proxy = new WebProxy(myProxy);
        string result = wc.DownloadString(url);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //log exception
    }
}
```

I have few proxies and almost all of them work well with above code.
However, sometimes the response return time is very very long (over an hour) and I believe it's due to my proxy slow issue.
But I don't understand that why it didn't throw exception since the webclient class should have an default timeout (I search default timeout that it should be 100 seconds).

Therefore I want to ask how to avoid this case?
Thanks everyone.

Comment: does it ever hit the exception code..? are you actually logging anything from what I see.. it's just a comment you need to provide more information.. also could this also be a network issue.. can you pinpoint the one that takes the longest.. post the url so someone can test / try it as well .

Comment: Timeouts only apply to a complete lack of response. If data is being transferred, however slowly, or if there seems to be any response in progress from the server at all, it's unlikely the timeout would apply. In any case, your question seems lot more about network configuration than anything else. If you really believe this is a _programming_ question, then you need to provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: Hi MethodMan, I have made a break point inside the catch and it never hit the exception code and actually there is some code inside to write the log but I didn't include it in the post. The code takes longest one is "string result = wc.DownloadString(url);". The url is any url also have the same issue such as google.com.

Comment: Hi Peter, really? I just thought that the timeout setting will throw the exception when it is over the period whatever any reason of it.
my question is how to avoid this case such as if it didn't response the result within 2 minutes then throw the exception. Originally I think the timeout setting will help me to do it but it didn't.

Comment: WebClient doesnt have timeout. You must derive from it and add timeout in webrequest in it. Search in google for webclient timeout.

Comment: Avoid using WebClient; use HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 0):

It will be complicated as you need two threads - one for download and one for cancellation on timeout.

```
wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
wc.Proxy = new WebProxy(myProxy);

string result = null;
var waitCancel = new CancellationTokenSource();

wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Cancelled) return;

    waitCancel.Cancel();

    result = e.Result;
};

wc.DownloadStringAsync(url);

waitCancel.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(30 * 1000);
if (waitCancel.IsCancellationRequested == false)
{
    wc.CancelAsync();
}

Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

WebClient doesnt have Timeout. You must extend it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  internal class Program
  {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      using (var webClient = new WebClientTimeOut())
      {
        webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        webClient.Proxy = new WebProxy(myProxy);
        try
        {
          var response = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.go1ogle.com");
          Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public class WebClientTimeOut : WebClient
  {
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
      var w = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
      w.Timeout = 1000;  // Timeout 1 second
      return w;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually I find that the issue is not related to timeout, but thanks anyway:)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make use of the "new" HttpClient for .Net, below I will illustrate in two steps

HttpClient has handlers you can place in a chain and then control how the whole client behaves, so in this case we will add a progress handler that will dictate behavior in regard to the speed of the transfer

if the transfer is too slow then cancel it and start a new one with different proxy in ur case ...

1. **Create the progress handler (to tell us how the progress is going .. If too slow then throw an exception)**

Type :

> ProgressMessageHandler
>   "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.handlers.progressmessagehandler(v=vs.118).aspx"

- Note : Package (System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension) required

We will wrap it with an own object to erase testing and configuring to certain expected transfer rate

Code :

```
    public class MyOwnProgressHandlerContainer
    {
        private readonly long _expectedBytesTransferred;
        private long _lastRecoredBytesTransferred = 0;

        public MyOwnProgressHandlerContainer(long expectedBytesTransferred)
        {
            _expectedBytesTransferred = expectedBytesTransferred;
        }

        public void ReceivedProgressHandler(object sender, HttpProgressEventArgs e)
        {
            // you can uses e.ProgressPercentage but this is calculated based on content length
            // http header which is very much ignored nowadays
            if (_lastRecoredBytesTransferred != 0 && e.BytesTransferred < (_lastRecoredBytesTransferred + _expectedBytesTransferred))
                throw new Exception("Too Slow, Abort !");

            _lastRecoredBytesTransferred = e.BytesTransferred;
        }

        public void SendProgressHandler(object sender, HttpProgressEventArgs e)
        {
            // write stuff to handle here when sending data (mainly for post or uploads)
            Console.WriteLine("Sent data ...");
        }
    }
```

2. **Create the HttpClient and inject the handlers that we wrapped :)**

Type :

> HttpClient
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx

Code :

```
    // set expected rate
    int expectedTransferRate = 25000; // AKA 2.5Mbps

    // create own handler instance 
    MyOwnProgressHandlerContainer myHandler = new MyOwnProgressHandlerContainer(expectedTransferRate);

    // create "ProgressMessageHandler"
    ProgressMessageHandler progresshandler = new ProgressMessageHandler();

    // Hookup event (send)
    progresshandler.HttpSendProgress += myHandler.SendProgressHandler; // these are delegates so they can be a part of a stat-full class

    // Hookup event (Receive)
    progresshandler.HttpReceiveProgress += myHandler.ReceivedProgressHandler; // these are delegates so they can be a part of a stat-full class

    // Create proxy handler
    HttpClientHandler httpClientProxyHandler = 
        new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy("http://localhost:8888", false),
            UseProxy = true
        };

    // Create client from factory with progress and "proxy" in your case  
    using (HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientFactory.Create(progresshandler, httpClientProxyHandler))
    {
        try
        {
            string downloadResult =
                httpClient
                    // get result (progress handlers are notified based on sent / received data)
                    .GetAsync("https://httpbin.org/image/svg") 
                    // could be a stream to read file content
                    .Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; 

                Console.WriteLine(downloadResult);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // inspected if the exception is the same as the on u throw in    MyOwnProgressHandlerContainer
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining so details!! But seems it's too complicated for me.